# The layout is incorrect after remove widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am implement my project using pyqt5. Currently, I have a window including many widget. Now, I want to remove some widgets. The window looks like:

[image]

Now, I want to remove the 'name1' widget including the QLabel and QPushButton.

However, after removing all 'name1' widgets, the 'name2' widgets including QLabel and QPushButton can not self-adapte with the window, like:

[image]

All my code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initGUI()
        self.show()

    def initGUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        removeLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.__removeText = QLineEdit()

        self.__removeBtn = QPushButton('Remove')
        self.__removeBtn.clicked.connect(self.remove)
        removeLayout.addWidget(self.__removeText)
        removeLayout.addWidget(self.__removeBtn)

        ROIsLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        for name in ['name1', 'name2']:
            subLayout = QHBoxLayout()
            subText = QLabel(name)
            subText.setObjectName(name)
            subBtn = QPushButton(name)
            subBtn.setObjectName(name)

            subLayout.addWidget(subText)
            subLayout.addWidget(subBtn)
            ROIsLayout.addLayout(subLayout)

        layout.addLayout(removeLayout)
        layout.addLayout(ROIsLayout)
        self.__ROIsLayout = ROIsLayout


    def remove(self, checked=False):
        name = self.__removeText.text()
        while True:
            child = self.__ROIsLayout.takeAt(0)
            if child == None:
                break
            while True:
                subChild = child.takeAt(0)
                if subChild == None:
                    break
                obName = subChild.widget().objectName()
                if name == obName:
                    widget = subChild.widget()
                    widget.setParent(None)
                    child.removeWidget(widget)
                    self.__ROIsLayout.removeWidget(widget)
                    del widget

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

update:

Actually, the issue may be the `takeAt`. The following code is workable:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initGUI()
        self.show()

    def initGUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        removeLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.__removeText = QLineEdit()

        self.__removeBtn = QPushButton('Remove')
        self.__removeBtn.clicked.connect(self.remove)
        removeLayout.addWidget(self.__removeText)
        removeLayout.addWidget(self.__removeBtn)

        ROIsLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        for name in ['name1', 'name2']:
            subLayout = QHBoxLayout()
            subLayout.setObjectName(name)
            subText = QLabel(name, parent=self)
            subText.setObjectName(name)
            subBtn = QPushButton(name, parent=self)
            subBtn.setObjectName(name)

            subLayout.addWidget(subText)
            subLayout.addWidget(subBtn)
            ROIsLayout.addLayout(subLayout)
            print(name, subLayout, subText, subBtn)

        layout.addLayout(removeLayout)
        layout.addLayout(ROIsLayout)
        self.__ROIsLayout = ROIsLayout

        self.record = [subLayout, subText, subBtn]


    def remove(self, checked=False):

        
        layout = self.record[0]
        txt = self.record[1]
        btn = self.record[2]

        layout.removeWidget(txt)
        txt.setParent(None)
        txt.deleteLater()

        layout.removeWidget(btn)
        btn.setParent(None)
        btn.deleteLater()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But, I have printed the QLabel/QPushButton in the self.record, and I find it is the same with that from child.takeAt(0).widget().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your code is that you're constantly using `takeAt()`. The result is that all items in the `__ROIsLayout` layout will be removed from it (but not deleted), which, in your case, are the sub layouts. This is clearly not a good approach: only the widgets with the corresponding object name will be actually deleted, while the others will still be "owned" by their previous parent, will still be visible at their previous position and their geometries won't be updated since they're not managed by the layout anymore.

There are multiple solutions to your question, all depending on your needs.

If you need to remove *rows* from a layout, I'd consider setting the object name on the layout instead, and look for it using `self.findChild()`.

Also consider that, while Qt allows setting the same object name for more than one object, that's not suggested.

Finally, while using `del` is normally enough, it's usually better to call [`deleteLater()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) for all Qt objects, which ensures that Qt correctly removes all objects (and related parentship/connections).

Another possibility, for this specific case, is to use a [QFormLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly reply. I still have two questions. (1) I do constantly using takeAt(), why the ```subLayout``` would be removed? I only remove widget by ```child.removeWidget(widget)```. If ```takeAt()``` is not suitable, how can I find the widget that should be removed? (2) I have tried that ```subLayout.deleteLater()```, but it still don't work. Could you please show me a workable code?

Comment: You have to delete both the layout *and* the children.